# How can I create a relational database for a "time-logging" service?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I currently have a database of customers. I would like to be able to query the database and see the list of dates the customer has made an appointment. For example, if I select John Doe, I want to be able to see that he had an appointment on June 6th, July 2nd, and July 24th, etc. and the total cost of the appointment. I feel like I can probably do this using a relational database, but I can't figure out a really good structure. Would a table of dates be a parent to the child customer table?

Thank you!

Comment: You dont need a table of dates,just create an appointment table with a foreign key to customer_id,throw in a datetime and cost column and you`re good.

Comment: You're right! That's exactly what I'll do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mihai, I'll create an appointment table that links customers with a datetime value!